# How to check if font exist in iOS4 at runtime

Tags: iphone, fonts, ios4, ipa

I wish to check at runtime whether a font exists on the device (iphone/ipad)?

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a legit question...

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to get a list of all fonts available:

```
// List all fonts on iPhone
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
  NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
  fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
      [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
  for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
  {
      NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
  }
  [fontNames release];
}
[familyNames release];
```

Based on this code you can easily build an NSArray with all font names and then use it to verify if your font is there, or any kind of workflow is more appropriate to your app.

[source](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 4):

you could try by using the `UIFont`  **fontWithName** method , i feel it should return **nil** for the font which does'nt exist in iOS.

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but then you are "shooting in the dark". It's easier to do this if a font *does* exist, then if it doesn't, since more fonts are not available on iOS then those that are.